# C# - Datagridview does not show data from MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a datagridview which should contain all users in mysql database. For my problem, it adds rows based on the number of rows in the MySQL, but does not show any data on it. see image below (i have 2 rows in database):

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbPHL.png)

Here's my code that I've tried:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace SampleDatabaseQueries
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        MySqlConnection conn;
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connString = "server=localhost;user=root;password=;database=test_db";
            conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);

            showData();
        }

        public void showData()
        {

            string query = "SELECT * FROM test_db.users;";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dTable);

            dgUsers.DataSource = dTable;

            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: above code works, data was already loaded but it adds another column so I did not see at first (as you can see the long horizontal scroll on the above screenshot). To solve that, I removed the columns I manually added and changed my query to:

```
SELECT username AS Username, password AS Password FROM test_db.users;
```

Thank you!

Comment: I would look at the DataTable in the debugger and make sure the column names match the source column names in the table properties.

Comment: I would also NOT use class- level commands or connections.  Just create them when you need them and dispose of them when they're not needed anymore (even if an exception is thrown).  A useful way to do that is with `using` blocks.

Comment: the names are the same. You mean I should only make the connString, conn, etc from my main_load to every methods that I do?

Comment: No - make them in the method that uses them.  I see no compelling reason to pass them from `Main_Load`  If anything you could store the connection string at a class level if that is "constant".  It won;t solve your immediate problem, though, just a suggestion for improvement.  Can you post the properties of the DataTable (preferably the code from `InitializeComponent`)?

Comment: oh I see, forgive me as  this is my first time dealing with c# with mysql, but How am I suppose to "post the properties of the DataTable", is it from the Server Explorer? when I'm clicking the users table I'm getting an error "Cannot create a design window for the selected object.", but I can see all the columns in that table and their properties.

Comment: An easy way to see that code is to doubleclick the datatable and then delete the code that was generated. you will get an error. double click that error and you can see the initializeComponent code.

Comment: @user6583346 No forgiveness needed - it's not _wrong_ to do what you're doing, but if you get in the habit of creating connections and commands only when needed, you'll avoid a lot of problems down the road.

Comment: is it from here? http://i.imgur.com/140F4xD.png . I'm getting an error when I'm doubleclicking the users (table).

Comment: Seems like columns you created in `DataGridView` have wrong `DataPropertyName`. To check if your loading code working properly check that `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true` -> then you will see result

Comment: @Fabio thank you, still nothing shows.

Comment: Is this winforms?

Comment: yes, winforms, anyways I was dumb, did not see that it's already loaded in the datagridview, but it adds additional columns so I did not see (as you can see the horizontal scroll from the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbPHL.png) . I made the columns manually, is it possible to put the data there and not add another column when loading from the database so I can put different column headers?

Comment: Do the additional columns have the same name and type as the manually added columns?

Comment: different name, but manage to change it using this query: SELECT username AS Username, password AS Password FROM test_db.users; anyways problem has been solved! thank you!

Comment: Put name you want in Column header of DataGridView and then set `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false`. Only `DataPropertyName` must be same as column name in `DataTable`

Comment: @Fabio that sounds interesting but when I put that autogeneratecolumns = false in my code it still generates another column, and when I tried to put it first it doesn't add the data/column in the dgv.

Comment: It will not generate any columns - you will have only columns you have created in designer. Unless you have some other code which add columns

Comment: I'm using the code by Gertjan in EDIT 1 below.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
```

With:

```
using (MySqlDataAdapter reader = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    adapter.Fill(dTable);
}
```

**EDIT**

For further improvement you could make a database connection class, i suppose you are using the MySql connector from oracle so you can check out their documentation on how to do this. Here is a link that can get you started on the most basic things like connecting and filling datatables: [MySql connector documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials.html)

**EDIT 1**

As you said my solution did not work, here is another one that I just tested and should work.

```
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
conn.Open();
string query = "SELECT * FROM test_db.users;";
MysqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
using (MySqlDataAdapter reader = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    adapter.Fill(dTable);
}
dgUsers.DataSource = dTable;
conn.Close();
```

This should work. If the datatable is not showing any rows(Empty rows means it found something), then there is a different problem, maybe your database is empty.

Comment: thanks, my code went like this: DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
            using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(dTable);
            } dgUsers.DataSource = dTable; but still getting no data showing in the datagrid.

Comment: While a good improvement, I highly doubt this solves the underlying problem.

Comment: @EDIT 1, still nothing shows (3 empty rows, in my database it has 2 rows, the other 1 is the datagrid autoadd row or something.) When I remove the showData() in the Main_Load, datagridview show only 1 row, which is its default, so we know from there that it's retrieving data from database but it doesn't show them. My database isn't empty, I don't know if its a property setting of Datagridview?

Comment: let me try to replicate this, What database are you using? Phpmyadmin and wamp or something?

Comment: I'm using mysql 5.7

Comment: Could you try filling the datagridview manually? Go to your form click on the datagridview element. In the top right of the datagridview a small arrow appears. Click it then set datasource to your datatable in your database.

Comment: change dgUsers.DataSource = dTable; to dgUsers.DataSource = dTable.Copy();

Comment: When I tried to add DataSource in the datagridview, it says that I have a database connection already. I added the data connection through the server explorer first when I created the login form.

Comment: omg I feel like dumb, did not see that the datagrid adds another column and it shows the data from there but using the horizontal scroll, but it also show the user_id (PK) which should not, how can I do that? Is it possible to add the data from the columns I added manually, so I can put different column headers?

Comment: If i understand correctly you want different column header, The way to do that is to change your query. so for example if your users table has ID, Name and Phone then you can do this.  string query = "SELECT ID as `Identification`, Name as `Fullname`, Phone as `Phone numer` FROM test_db.users;". You can google "SQL AS keyword" to get a better explanation

Comment: No problem glad I could help, You can edit your post so people know how you fixed it in the future.